# SSH private key authentication not working in Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I recently created a new VM running Ubuntu 20.04.3 server, and to use key pair authentication for the SSH server, I created the key pair with `ssh-keygen` and enabled `PubkeyAuthentication yes` within `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I'm unable SSH in via:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@192.168.1.6
```

- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: 
   <sup>(Turning off password authentication and allowing only key authentication didn't work either)</sup>

  ```
  Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

  PermitRootLogin yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes

  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

  UsePAM yes

  X11Forwarding yes
  PrintMotd no

  AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

  Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
  ```
- I want to be able to log in to the server without having the public key within the server's `authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1):

> I tried turning off password authentication and allowing only key authentication, but it didn't work either.

If key authentication doesn't work, then it doesn't work *independently* from other authentication types. They don't interfere with each other.

> (Without having the public key on the server's authorized_keys file)

It's not going to work that way. Literally anyone can generate their own id_rsa keypair – having the public key on the server's authorized_keys file is how the server actually knows that *it's your key* rather than someone else's.

Comment: Appreciate your response, not to mention that I don't understand what you are saying. But I have seen people using the private key (id_rsa) to log in to servers in some CTF events (Capture The Flags). I am hoping there must be some kind of configuration change that should be done. Pardon me if I am being stupid.

Comment: They are using it, yes, but that's actually the whole point of this entire authentication scheme: you don't choose to use the one _or_ the other – you always use both the private _and_ public keys in the same procedure. So yes, you will generally see people using a private key, but this works _because_ the server knows the corresponding public key.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The public key inside the `authorized_keys` file on the server, in the user's `~/.ssh` folder you're trying to connect to is essentially the keyhole. You need it to connect to said user using the corresponding private key.

You have `PermitRootLogin` set to `yes` so I'm guessing that also might be something you're trying to do. If you are trying to use root to connect, you might want to make sure that the 'authorized_keys' file that you're trying to use to connect to is in the `/root/.ssh/` folder.

If that's the case, you might also want to set: `PermitRootLogin` to `prohibit-password`, I'm not certain if it's needed though certainly it would be more secure.

You will eventually probably also want to set `PasswordAuthentication` back to `no`.

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to ssh as root. I just want to ssh in as the user.

Comment: Oh well, that might be something you'd want to set to no as well. Anyway, if that's not the case then weird that it's not working. Maybe there was just a typo or file misplaced somewhere and you just need to try again.